# Django: How to achieve logical mapping between form fields and model fields?

Tags: django

If I have:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
    generic_field = CharField()
```

and

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    field_x       = models.CharField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    field_y       = models.CharField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    field_z       = models.CharField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

and in a view:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    my_form = MyForm(
     {'field_x': generate_field_x(request.POST['generic_field']), 'field_y': generate_field_y(request.POST['generic_field']),
     'field_z': generate_field_z(request.POST['generic_field']),
     },
     request.POST)
```

This works well to marshal generic_field onto the correct model field. The problem occurs when there is/are validation errors. How do I marshal model validation errors (field_x/y/z) back onto generic_field? The goal is to get the user to seamlessly interact with generic_field, validation and all.

Disclaimer: 1. I'm new to Django, pls excuse any clumsiness in my post. 2. I did dig around and hit brick walls everywhere, possibly because I don't know how to phrase this properly. Please help/point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague, but it sounds like you want to [create a custom field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/) that maps to multiple concrete fields in the model, but has a single presence in a form.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Ignacio. What I'm trying to achieve is to have a non-persistent field on the form (generic_field), whose contents I programatically assign to model fields (field_x,field_y,field_z) at will when user POSTs the form, and I want to retrofit any generated field errors to the non-persistent form.

Comment: The last line is meant to say "...I want to retrofit any generated field errors to the non-persistent form field"

Comment: But *why* do you want that? What's the problem you're trying to solve? There's almost certainly a better way.

Comment: Hi Daniel... Unfortunately, this discussion can only be hypothetical :-( I was made to sign a non-disclosure agreement to that effect.

The long and the short of it is that users' lives will be simplified if they could supply, say, an ID number and have the app deduce gender, age, etc, based on the ID number... I couldn't think of anything simpler than to have the hypothetical ID number field which maps to gender, age, etc, on the model.

Comment: As it turns out, subclassing CharField and performing the validation in there has been the least complicated solution. Hope it either  helps if anyone ever runs into this or that someone else might suggest something better. Thanks Ignacio